# Місцева говірка в документах

Tags: діалектизми

Чи можна використовувати у офіційних заявах, зверненнях, службових записках  місцеву говірку, мотивуючи це тим, що «це особливість регіону проживання того, хто звертається і він є носієм даного типу говірки»? Чи таке недопустимо в офіційній або службовій документації, навіть якщо вона стосується тільки внутрішнього службового користування?

Answer (score 1):

Відповідно з [вимогами до складання та оформлення текстів документів](http://pidruchniki.com/1005072838353/dokumentoznavstvo/vimogi_skladannya_oformlennya_tekstiv_dokumentiv#93)

> Документ (лат. доказ) - це засіб закріплення всілякими способами на
>   спеціальному матеріалі інформації про факти, події, явища об'єктивної
>   дійсності і розумової діяльності людини.

Всі документи складаються [українською літературною мовою](http://pidruchniki.com/1099021438351/dokumentoznavstvo/ukrayinska_literaturna_mova_normi#31) не залежно від регіону проживання

> Українська літературна національна мова сформувалася на основі
>   найбільш уніфікованого й поширеного діалекту, в основі якого лежать
>   середньонаддніпрянські говірки, але увібрала в себе і найважливіші
>   елементи інших діалектів України. 
>   Літературна мова - це нормована мова з
>   погляду лексики, граматики, орфографії, орфоепії (тобто це певні
>   критерії вживання слів та речень).

Існує [Державний стандарт на оформлення документів управління та реквізити документів](http://pidruchniki.com/1392091838354/dokumentoznavstvo/derzhavniy_standart_oformlennya_dokumentiv_upravlinnya_rekviziti_dokumentiv#62)

> Постановою Держкомітету стандартів з 01.01.91 в дію введено ГОСТ
>   6.38-90. Це науково обґрунтовані правила підготовки та оформлення документів. Введення таких правил створює необхідні передумови для
>   детальнішої уніфікації документів, що у свою чергу сприятиме
>   використанню їх в автоматизованих системах управління.

***Отже, в  офіційній або службовій документації, навіть якщо вона стосується тільки внутрішнього службового користування не допустимо вживати місцеву говірку.***